# CEF3. How set flag UR_FLAG_ALLOW_STORED_CREDENTIALS?

Tags: c++, chromium-embedded

I try this code

```
void WebApp::OnContextInitialized() {
```

...

```
    CefBrowserHost::CreateBrowser(window_info, handler, url, browser_settings, nullptr, nullptr);
```

...

```
    CefRefPtr<CefRequest> request = CefRequest::Create();
    CefRefPtr<MyRequestClient> client = new MyRequestClient();
    CefRefPtr<CefURLRequest> url_request = CefURLRequest::Create(request, client.get(), nullptr);
    request->SetFlags(UR_FLAG_ALLOW_STORED_CREDENTIALS);  // or any other flag
```

// here I get error "FATAL:request_impl.cc(354)] Check failed: false. object is read only"

```
    url_request->Cancel(); }
```

Help me, please, to set flag.

PS. Visual Studio 19, CEF3 from cef_binary_94.4.10+g38a7995+chromium-94.0.4606.81_windows64

Comment: Set the flag before you call CefURLRequest::Create

Comment: I turn on this flag but get message:
"A preload for 'https://yastatic.net/s3/passport-static/core/v0.2.223-12/css/react.authv2.cij.css' is found, but is not used because the request credentials mode does not match. Consider taking a look at crossorigin attribute."
I read https://bitbucket.org/chromiumembedded/cef/wiki/GeneralUsage about cros-origin but i don't use custom schemes (I think).
PS. I want the browser to remember my account
PPS. Sorry for bad English. It's not my native language. I use google translator.

Comment: CEF has it's own support forum at https://magpcss.org/ceforum/index.php best place to ask